# Custom width for cell in UITableViewStyleGrouped tableviews

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In the iPhone SDK, is there a way to customize the width of the cells in a tableview that is having the style of UITableViewStyleGrouped?

The problem is that I am using an custom background image (width of 290px) for the cell.backgroundView but apparently that gets stretched. I want to be able to set the custom width of this cell so the background image doesn't stretch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just resize the tableView as per your requirement ..........either from Nib or programmatically.....

size of cell depends on the width of table.

**because there is not such any method in IPhoneSDK**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView widthForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// width
return 300;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you not call the delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView widthForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// width
return 300;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think this will work. I just tried it out myself.

Comment: There is no method for width in the UITableViewDelegate